# xslt 2.0 how replace $ by escaped dollar (for conversion to LaTeX)

Tags: xslt, replace, escaping, latex

I am new to XSLT. I googled extensively but couldn't figure out how to do the following:

I am transforming XML to LaTeX. Of course, LaTeX needs to escape characters such as $ and #. I tried the following in the replace function but it does not work. (They do work without the replace function.)

```
<xsl:template match="xyz:doc">
\subsubsection{<xsl:value-of select="replace( xyz:headline, '(\$)', '\$1' )"/>}  
...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xyz:doc">
\subsubsection{<xsl:value-of select="replace( xyz:headline, '\$', '\$' )"/>}  
...
</xsl:template>
```

Possible content to be escaped is:
"Locally defined field #931" or
"Locally defined subfield $b"

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please show some sample input string and the corresponding output you want to create using `replace` and XSLT/XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace a dollar symbol `$` in the input with `\$` in the output then use `replace(xyz:headline, '\$', '\\\$')`.

If there are several characters that need the same escaping then `replace(xyz:headline, '([$#])', '\\$1')` should do.

Sample at http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqX/1