# Ampersand, XSLT and LaTeX

Tags: xslt, latex, ampersand

I'm struggling with something basic in a transformation from – well actually Google Tables to XML to LaTeX. My main problem is this: how to pass through ampersands from one end to to the other.

I know similar questions have been answered several times, but there doesn't seem to be a working solution. (The best help so far seems to me this: [xslt 2.0 how replace $ by escaped dollar (for conversion to LaTeX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592977/xslt-2-0-how-replace-by-escaped-dollar-for-conversion-to-latex) )

Let's say I have the publishing house "Simon & Schuster" in Google Tables. After I export it and import it into XML it's:

```html
<xml>
  <name>
    <publisher>Simon &amp; Schuster</publisher>
  </name>
</xml>
```

Now in LaTeX I prepared a new command so to minimize the ampersand-problem:

```html
\newcommand{\ampersand}{\&}
```

When I get to the XSLT (2.0) it get's (too) tricky:

```html
<xsl:function name="foo:ampersand-replace">
    <xsl:param name="passed-string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($passed-string, '\&amp', '\\\ampersand')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="publisher">
     <xsl:value of select="foo:ampersand-replace(publisher)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

because this does not compile (Saxxon 9.6). The problem is of course the Ampersand: Syntax Error Escape character not allowed.

I tried a different approach, too:

```html
<xml>
  <name>
    <publisher>Simon <c rendition="#ampersand"/> Schuster</publisher>
  </name>
</xml>
```

The problem there is, that I can't use the

```html
<xsl:value-of/>
```

-command, as well as the c is not processed. 
Any idea what I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `xsl:function` needs to look like this:

```
<xsl:function name="foo:ampersand-replace">
    <xsl:param name="passed-string"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($passed-string, '&amp;', '\\ampersand')"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Also note that when you call it, your current template is matching `publisher`, so you are positioned on that and so the call to the function should look like this...

```
<xsl:template match="publisher">
    <xsl:value-of select="foo:ampersand-replace(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```